# Blade Runner 2049: Joi and Replicant tech related?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

One thing that is established is that Wallace is involved in not just Replicant manufacture but farming (it may be that synthetic farming uses related technology but that seems unlikely since there is need for the worms or whatever to reproduce, i would think and maybe even this is significant -- he can get lower lifeforms to reproduce but humans is a different thing) and of course Joi. I wonder if it is meant for the audience to infer that Joi and Replicants share technology -- the minds of Joi and Replicants are built in the same way? I find this compelling -- it explains why he interacts with Joi so well, much better than with humans with whom it is clearly shown he has no friendly relations at all.

Comment: Yes, both technologies are very strongly connected. In the same way that Google Search and Google Home are related.

Comment: Not an answer, but it seems to me Replicants are more like "human clones altered both physically and mentally" (possibly with inorganic and organic parts), while Joi is more like ChatGPT, Girlfriend Edition. I would guess they are entirely unrelated technologies.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/255148/21267