# Right before Luv destroyed the mobile emanator she says, "I hope you enjoyed our product" -- addressed to whom?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

Until I saw a video discussing Joi's consciousness or lack thereof and the possibility that when Luv was about to crush the emanator that the remark was to Joi about K, I had not considered this.

But the idea that Luv was saying to Joi that she hoped that Joi had enjoyed K the replicant is a pretty interesting one. I am not convinced. Luv could have been talking about the emanator itself or was looking at Joi but the remark was for K although K was not conscious.

Comment: Luv was definitely talking to K in reference to Joi. Any other interpretation is just reading too much into it.

Comment: It would be great if you link the video as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Luv was definitely referring to Joi

### All three are products

Luv, Joi and K are all products of Wallace Corp. It is a strange dynamic that they're in, all some version of Android or Artificial Intelligence.

### Their positions and differences

#### Luv

Luv, who is a sort of 'favoured pet' to Wallace, has grown accustomed to thinking that she's superior. She even falsely believes that Wallace calling her "Luv" is him giving her a name - when in fact, he's only calling her "Love", which is a diminutive.

When K first meets Luv, they have this interaction:

> *Luv comes toward K. Hands tucked. Suit sensible. Every
>
> aspect immaculate. The flawless representative.
>
> LUV (cont’d)*
> Another prodigal serial number returns.
> A 30 year old open case finally closed is
> a curiosity and relief. Thank you,
> Officer. I’m here for Mr. Wallace.
> *(hand out)*
> I’m Luv.
> *K*
> He named you. You must be special.
> *He steals a once over, understanding. She gives an
>
> unembarrassed nod of confession.*
> <sub>*-Blade Runner 2049, Final Shooting Script, Fancher, H. and Green, M. 2017.*</sub>

But later on, she and Wallace have this interaction:

> *NIANDER WALLACE (cont’d)*
> Bring the one for micronics, would you, luv.
> *Ah, “luv.” A diminutive. Not a name at all, though taken
>
> for one.*
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

This doesn't stop her from getting that sense of superiority (this will be important later).

#### K

K is our protagonist. He's supposed to be as generic as possible (for an Android). Much has been written about him and his purpose, so I won't delve deep into it here.

See:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215353/21267
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/181741/21267

The main things to note about him is that he *longs to be human*. He jumps at every opportunity to convince himself he's real, or special. He wants to be a "Special K".

#### Joi

Joi is an interesting mix within all of this. She's the protagonist's catalyst in many aspects - she supports him, encourages him, questions him, and most importantly *loves him*. But there's a twist, she's also a creation of Wallace's, with the tagline of "Does whatever you please" - the ultimate pleasure bot.

Her position in K's life and in the story is to question what is *real* - what is *real **love***.

### Luv has already set up the reference to Joi as a product

You'll recall when K first meets Luv in Wallace's headquarters, Luv mentions Joi and *specifically* refers to her as a product:

> *INT. SMALL BASEMENT CORRIDOR.
>
> K and Luv walking in a small basement corridor. A chime
> comes out of K’s pocket: his emanator.*
> *LUV*
> I see you are also a customer. Are you
> satisfied with our product?
> *K*
> She's very realistic.
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

### Final blow

There's a lot more to this scene than what you might have thought initially, the screenplay does this scene a lot more justice. Basically, at this point, Luv having become quite frustrated with K and all these proceedings, relishes the fact that she can hurt K - *emotionally*.

We see that K and Joi's relationship keeps on growing, and no matter what we think and see about Joi's reality, [it was real to *him*](https://youtu.be/uejcXgxxEh8?t=15), and that's all that matters!

> *Luv stops to watch K’s slow progress. Curious. KICKS him
>
> again with her strange strength. K LANDS HARD. Bone snaps.
>
> THE EMANATOR GOES FLYING.
>
> K is on his back -- breath short -- then CUT OFF as LUV
>
> STOMPS HIS CHEST. His insides rupture.
>
> Luv steps close. Ready to end him when --
>
> JOI (O.S.)*
> STOP!
> *JOI HAS PROJECTED
>
> Enough of a distraction that Luv for the moment leaves K.
>
> Steps over ahead of K to... The emanator.
>
> Luv sees K reach and crawl for it. Trying to reach it before
>
> she does.
>
> Luv locks eyes with Joi. Raises a foot.
>
> K shakes his head. Don’t.*
> *Luv thrills at the chance to administer such a unique pain.
>
> LUV*
> I do hope you’re satisfied with our
> product.
> *K and Joi meet eyes. Breath held. She knows what’s coming.
>
> Spends her last moment looking at K, loving him.
>
> Joi reaches a hand toward his. Just enough time to say it.*
> *JOI*
> I love y--
> *And Luv CRUSHES the emanator with her boot.*
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

So that's how and why Luv is referring to K, because she realises she can hit him where it hurts, so to speak.

### The fallout

This is where it gets really interesting for K. His one hope for love has been not only squashed physically, but he realises that there's a chance that all of Joi's interactions with him were just, *fake*. All part of her programming to please him. Just another of Wallace's **products**.

## Your specific concerns addressed

Luv was looking at Joi, but she was addressing K. K was conscious enough to give the pleading look of "don't" and for Joi to tell him she loves him.

Also, K was not a pleasure bot; he was a Blade Runner. His purpose was not to please or to satisfy, but to merely be a detective and retire defective Replicants. In other words, K was not Joi's product, Joi was K's.

Comment: I do hope you're satisfied with my answer.

Comment: Well, story writer Michael Green doesn't disagree: https://twitter.com/andmichaelgreen/status/1450601762734280705

Comment: Mooz: Is it true that the writer of the screenplay read this post and agreed? Amazing.

Comment: @releseabe It is. Michael and I were on good terms for a while and he gave me some insights and verified some things for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say she's saying it to herself - only she'll find it clever. There must be thousands of examples of bad guys saying something witty to their already dead victim because the audience can still enjoy it and the killer is rather proud of themselves.

Like in Total Recall "Consider it a divorce." Doesn't mean Arnold's Quaid thinks his wife Sharon Stone's character is listening anymore - well unless she's a ghost.

Sure K might have heard it and in Total Recall Melina heard it - but the person it's meant for is the ego of the character that said it.  It's a getting the last word victory.